# How to prove: $-\frac{1}{\sec2x}=\frac{\cos^3x-\sin^3x}{\cos x +\sin x}+\frac{\cos2x}{(\cos x +\sin x)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you do it?
I'm really stuck on this proof. Can someone please explain? Thanks

Comment: As a rule, it's usually a good idea to share what you've tried, even if it didn't work out. For one, it helps us to assess what sort of tools you have at your disposal, and better tailor our answers to your skill level. For another, if you were actually making progress, then it may be that you only need a little push to get "unstuck."

Comment: This is not an identity. Are you trying to figure out what values of $x$ make this true?

Answer (score 5):

If I plug in $x=0$ then the left hand side is -1 but the right hand side becomes $1+1=2$

Answer (score 0):

This equality is true for all
$$x=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi,\, n \in\mathbb{Z}.$$

There are no other real valued solutions. Your question did not indicate much, and this would be alot to type, so I leave you with this for now. You can verify this by solving the equation for $0$ and then massaging the trig side into a product of terms. I get a product of 3 terms, 2 never zero, and the third with this solution.